# When does the EXALT faction appear in XCOM: Enemy Within?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

When does the EXALT faction appear in XCOM: Enemy Within? Is it random or after a specific "story point," research milestone, or council mission?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From  [UFOPaedia](http://www.ufopaedia.org/index.php?title=XCOM:_Enemy_Within_%28EU2012%29#EXALT_.28New_Faction.29):

> EXALT always starts its operations at a random date in May, with the possible variation between dates dependent on the game's difficulty level. On Easy/Normal difficulties the day can vary between the 12th and the 24th, while on Classic/Impossible it can start anywhere between the 6th and the 24th.

For reference, the game begins in March, so May is the third in-game month.